# Read excel via ADO.NET with SQL Server commands?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, jet

I **can** read XLS file with this code :

```
string path =@"c:\r\1.xlsx";
OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + path + @"';HDR=Yes;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37");
OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
DataSet DtSet = new DataSet();
MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
...
...
```

However - when I enhance the query to include some SQL Server commands like

```
 select *,case when 1=1 then 'a' else 'b' end as rr  from [Sheet1$]
```

it goes BANG

[image]

I know that `OLEDB` is using `access` jet/ace behind the scenes.

How can use pure T-SQL query here?

Comment: Difficult, "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" can't understand SQLServer keywords like WHEN, on the other hand is not possible to use a different oledbprovider to connect to excel files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `IIF` in querying excel

```
select *,
    IIF(1 = 1, 'a', 'b') as rr  
from [Sheet1$]
```

And, to create a multiple case statement, just nest them, like this:

```
select *,
    IIF(1 = 1, 'a', IIF( 2 = 2, 'c', 'b')) as rr  
from [Sheet1$]
```

As to whether you can use a pure MSSQL query, I do not believe that any connection that you can use with excel supports the CASE statement. So, you will have to use the above solution

Comment: Correct, this resolve the case provided in the question, but not the question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, I believe that it is http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx

Comment: @Steve Sorry, I missed the main question and have updated appropriately